# Insert image and list inside a table

Tags: tables, graphics, lists

I am trying to add both an image and list inside a table but I face various problems. As shown in the picture, the image is above the first horizontal line and also the lists are not properly oriented, they are located at the end of the table, not in the same line with the image. 
Can anybody help me with that? Thanks a lot

```
     \begin{table}[h!]
     \begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{ | c | p{5cm} | p{5cm} | }
     \hline
      my.Lboro & Advantages & Disadvantages \\ \hline
     \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}
      & 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Accessibility
      \item Up to date information
      \item Fulfil students needs and wants \ldots
      \end{itemize}
      & 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item Accessibility
      \item Up to date information
      \item Fulfil students needs and wants \ldots
      \end{itemize}
      \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
      \label{tbl:myLboro}
      \end{center}
      \end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `\raisebox` to adjust the vertical positioning of the image:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% delete the demo option in your actual code
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
     \begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{ c  p{5cm}  p{5cm}  }
     \toprule
      my.Lboro & Advantages & Disadvantages \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
     \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth, height=60mm]{images/myLboro.png}}
      & 
      \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
      \item Accessibility
      \item Up to date information
      \item Fulfil students needs and wants \ldots
      \end{itemize}
      & 
      \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
      \item Accessibility
      \item Up to date information
      \item Fulfil students needs and wants \ldots
      \end{itemize}
      \\ \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{my.Lboro Analysis}
      \label{tbl:myLboro}
      \end{center}
      \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also made some changes to your code (as suggestions, of course):

1. I used the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to improve the table design (in particular, no vertical rules).
2. I used the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to suppress some vertical spacing before the lists.

Comment: You are amazing man, great solution. Thanks a lot, 10000 likes!!!! ;)

Answer (score 42):

The [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) provides the `m{<len>}` column type which vertically aligns content in rows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | m{5cm} | m{5cm} | }
    \hline
    my.Lboro & Advantages & Disadvantages \\ \hline
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=60mm]{tiger}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    %\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Accessibility
        \item Up to date information
        \item Fulfil students needs and wants \ldots
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    & 
    %\begin{minipage}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Accessibility
        \item Up to date information
        \item Fulfil students needs and wants \ldots
      \end{itemize}
    %\end{minipage}
    \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{my.Lboro Analysis}\label{tbl:myLboro}
\end{table}

\end{document}
​
```

Then, additionally, you can place the image inside a `minipage` of equivalent size (box it) to obtain the correct alignment. The [`adjustbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) provides a similar alignment modification for controlling boxes.

Comment: I like the flexibility of this approach - thanks