# Alignment of \includegraphics in a tabular

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

When putting a graphics inside a table, the text at the right is too much at the bottom

Minimum example :

```
\documentclass{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{graphicx} % This is already loaded by the atlasnote class
                       % Just use it to include your plots!

\begin{document}

abc
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
\hline
ABCD, put me at the top     &\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{invariant_mass_eX_Asymmetric}   &line1, i wish to be much more at the top\\
&                               &line2, idem\\
&                               &line3, idem\\
&                               &line4, idem\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

def

\end{document}
```

Current output:

[image]

I read the link [Insert image and list inside a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53061/insert-image-and-list-inside-a-table) but this didn't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 30):

The default alignment point of an image is its bottom edge you can use

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics}{...}}
```

To put the alignment in the middle, or more generally use any length instead of `-.5\height`
The `adjustbox` package offers some nicer syntax to such things.

Comment: ...and the syntax is `valign=c`.

Comment: thanks. it helps to put above the first line, but not the others.

Comment: @Joe Your `line2` is in the following row of the table so of course it comes below. perhaps you want to make the last column `p{3cm}` instead of `c` and then put `line 1... line2...` all in one multi-line entry

Comment: How to get rid of the annoying vertical white space on top of the image?

Comment: @yegor256 don't ask new questions as comments on years old answers to other questions. I have no idea which space you find annoying, please post a new question with an example document showing the bad space.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt...

- I changed the middle column of the table from an `l` column to a `p{5.2cm}` column. That puts the cells in that column in a paragraph of width 5.2cm (change that according to your image size).
- I put `\vspace{0cm}` before the image. Don't ask me why, but it seems to work ok!

Result:

[image]

Code (the `demo` option makes the black image placeholder):

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{graphicx} % This is already loaded by the atlasnote class
                       % Just use it to include your plots!

\begin{document}

abc
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{5.2cm}|c|}
\hline
ABCD, put me at the top     &\vspace{0cm}\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{invariant_mass_eX_Asymmetric}   &line1, i wish to be much more at the top\\
&                               &line2, idem\\
&                               &line3, idem\\
&                               &line4, idem\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

def

\end{document}
```

---

### Update

In response to the OP's request for line2, line3 and line4 to move upwards as well:

- Following David Carlisle's suggestion, you can use `\raisebox` to move the image downwards.
- You can then `smash` the image, which makes LaTeX think the image has no height. This trick means that the image could overlap the bottom of the table, but that won't be a problem if you have enough text in the other two columns.

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{graphicx} % This is already loaded by the atlasnote class
                       % Just use it to include your plots!

\begin{document}

abc
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|}
\hline
ABCD, put me at the top     &\smash{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{invariant_mass_eX_Asymmetric}}}   &line1, i wish to be much more at the top\\
&                               &line2, idem\\
&                               &line3, idem\\
&                               &line4, idem\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

def

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. my last problem is that i wish the line2, line3, line4 to be at the right of the figure, not at the "bottom". Do you have an idea ?

Comment: thank you very much. This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot, you made me save a huge amount of time.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider clicking on the tick mark next to my answer to 'accept' it, so that this question can be marked as resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using multirow.sty that works pretty well out of the box:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

abc
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
ABCD, put me at the top&
    \multirow{4}{*}{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{invariant_mass_eX_Asymmetric.pdf}}&
    line1, i wish to be much more at the top\\
&                               &line2, idem\\
&                               &line3, idem\\
&                               &line4, idem\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

def

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In my case, this leads to `Overfull \vbox` for the full height of the image. How to get rid of this?