# How to allign includegraphics and tabular when next to each other?

Tags: tables, subfloats

I am trying to align an image with a table, for some reason m the table is moved to the right. (It works fine when using two graphics)
[image: wrong alignment]

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \subfloat[Title 1\label{subfig-1}]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{HP-POS.png}
  }
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Title 2\label{subfig-2}]{%
    \begin{tabular}{l r}
        \toprule
            \textbf{POS-Tag} & \textbf{Anzahl} \\
        \midrule
            NN      & 13.189\\
            \$,     & 7.845\\
            VVFIN   & 7.693\\
            PPER    & 7.552\\
            \$.     & 6.843\\
            ART     & 6.698\\
            APPR    & 5.816\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{•}
  \label{fig:tabelle}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112976/alignment-of-includegraphics-in-a-tabular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer the [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=de) package:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

...

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{HP-POS.png}
    \caption{figtext}
    \label{fig:figure:figlabel}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \begin{tabular}{lr}
        \toprule
            POS-Tag & Anzahl \\
        \midrule
            NN      & 13.189\\
            \$,     & 7.845\\
            VVFIN   & 7.693\\
            PPER    & 7.552\\
            \$.     & 6.843\\
            ART     & 6.698\\
            APPR    & 5.816\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{tabtext}
    \label{fig:figure:tablabel}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{caption}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}
```

That way it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can move down image with (The default alignment point of an image is its bottom edge https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112977/122678)

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{HP-POS.png}}
```

Where `\height` define the height of included picture